# QuickSort example will not compile

Tags: c, warnings, quicksort

I found this example but when I get compilation warnings. If somebody could help me with this i'd appreciate it very much.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

/* qsort int comparison function */ 
int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    const int *ia = (const int *)a; // casting pointer types 
    const int *ib = (const int *)b;
    return *ia  - *ib; 
    /* integer comparison: returns negative if b > a 
    and positive if a > b */ 
} 

/* integer array printing function */ 
void print_int_array(const int *array, size_t len) 
{ 
    size_t i;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++) 
        printf("%d | ", array[i]);

    putchar('\n');
} 

/* sorting integers using qsort() example */ 
void sort_integers_example() 
{ 
    int numbers[] = { 7, 3, 4, 1, -1, 23, 12, 43, 2, -4, 5 }; 
    size_t numbers_len = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int);

    puts("*** Integer sorting...");

    /* print original integer array */ 
    print_int_array(numbers, numbers_len);

    /* sort array using qsort functions */ 
    qsort(numbers, numbers_len, sizeof(int), int_cmp);

    /* print sorted integer array */ 
    print_int_array(numbers, numbers_len);
} 

/* qsort C-string comparison function */ 
int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
    /* strcmp functions works exactly as expected from
    comparison function */ 
} 

/* C-string array printing function */ 
void print_cstring_array(char **array, size_t len) 
{ 
    size_t i;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++) 
        printf("%s | ", array[i]);

    putchar('\n');
} 

/* sorting C-strings array using qsort() example */ 
void sort_cstrings_example() 
{ 
    char *strings[] = { "Zorro", "Alex", "Celine", "Bill", "Forest", "Dexter" };
    size_t strings_len = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(char *);

    /** STRING */ 
    puts("*** String sorting...");

    /* print original string array */ 
    print_cstring_array(strings, strings_len);

    /* sort array using qsort functions */ 
    qsort(strings, strings_len, sizeof(char *), cstring_cmp);

    /* print sorted string array */ 
    print_cstring_array(strings, strings_len);
} 



/* an example of struct */ 
struct st_ex { 
    char product[16];
    float price;
};

/* qsort struct comparision function (price float field) */ 
int struct_cmp_by_price(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;
    return (int)(100.f*ia->price - 100.f*ib->price);
    /* float comparison: returns negative if b > a 
    and positive if a > b. We multiplied result by 100.0
    to preserve decimal fraction */ 

} 

/* qsort struct comparision function (product C-string field) */ 
int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;
    return strcmp(ia->product, ib->product);
    /* strcmp functions works exactly as expected from
    comparison function */ 
} 

/* Example struct array printing function */ 
void print_struct_array(struct st_ex *array, size_t len) 
{ 
    size_t i;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++) 
        printf("[ product: %s \t price: $%.2f ]\n", array[i].product, array[i].price);

    puts("--");
} 

/* sorting structs using qsort() example */ 
void sort_structs_example(void) 
{ 
    struct st_ex structs[] = {{"mp3 player", 299.0f}, {"plasma tv", 2200.0f}, 
                              {"notebook", 1300.0f}, {"smartphone", 499.99f}, 
                              {"dvd player", 150.0f}, {"matches", 0.2f }};

    size_t structs_len = sizeof(structs) / sizeof(struct st_ex);

    puts("*** Struct sorting (price)...");

    /* print original struct array */ 
    print_struct_array(structs, structs_len);

    /* sort array using qsort functions */ 
    qsort(structs, structs_len, sizeof(struct st_ex), struct_cmp_by_price);

    /* print sorted struct array */ 
    print_struct_array(structs, structs_len);

    puts("*** Struct sorting (product)...");

    /* resort using other comparision function */ 
    qsort(structs, structs_len, sizeof(struct st_ex), struct_cmp_by_product);    

    /* print sorted struct array */ 
    print_struct_array(structs, structs_len);
} 


/* MAIN program (calls all other examples) */ 
int main() 
{ 
    /* run all example functions */ 
    sort_integers_example();
    sort_cstrings_example();
    sort_structs_example();
    return 0;
} 

/*
Execution result:


*** Integer sorting...
7 | 3 | 4 | 1 | -1 | 23 | 12 | 43 | 2 | -4 | 5 | 
-4 | -1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 12 | 23 | 43 | 
*** String sorting...
Zorro | Alex | Celine | Bill | Forest | Dexter | 
Alex | Bill | Celine | Dexter | Forest | Zorro | 
*** Struct sorting (price)...
[ product: mp3 player    price: $299.00 ]
[ product: plasma tv     price: $2200.00 ]
[ product: notebook      price: $1300.00 ]
[ product: smartphone    price: $499.99 ]
[ product: dvd player    price: $150.00 ]
[ product: matches       price: $0.20 ]
--
[ product: matches       price: $0.20 ]
[ product: dvd player    price: $150.00 ]
[ product: mp3 player    price: $299.00 ]
[ product: smartphone    price: $499.99 ]
[ product: notebook      price: $1300.00 ]
[ product: plasma tv     price: $2200.00 ]
--
*** Struct sorting (product)...
[ product: dvd player    price: $150.00 ]
[ product: matches       price: $0.20 ]
[ product: mp3 player    price: $299.00 ]
[ product: notebook      price: $1300.00 ]
[ product: plasma tv     price: $2200.00 ]
[ product: smartphone    price: $499.99 ]
--
*/
```

My errors are as follows:

```
g++ -Wall -o "Qiksortfromnet" "Qiksortfromnet.cpp" (in directory: /home/dylan)
Qiksortfromnet.cpp: In function ‘void sort_cstrings_example()’:
Qiksortfromnet.cpp:68:79: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     char *strings[] = { "Zorro", "Alex", "Celine", "Bill", "Forest", "Dexter" };
                                                                               ^

 Qiksortfromnet.cpp:68:79: warning: deprecated conversion from string
 constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings] Qiksortfromnet.cpp:68:79:
 warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
 [-Wwrite-strings] Qiksortfromnet.cpp:68:79: warning: deprecated
 conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 Qiksortfromnet.cpp:68:79: warning: deprecated conversion from string
 constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings] Qiksortfromnet.cpp:68:79:
 warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
 [-Wwrite-strings] Compilation finished successfully.
```

Last edit from a previous user removed half of my errors/warnings... please do not do that !!!

Comment: change `char *strings[]` to `const char *strings[]`. String literals have the type `const char *`.

Comment: Just to be clear. These are warnings not errors (the `-Werror` compiler flag can turn these into actual compile errors but it does not appear to be the case here) . "Compilation finished successfully." - so it looks like your compile completed successfully.

Comment: @mch I get errors after doing that.

Comment: Note: `return *ia  - *ib;` risks `int` overflow, which is undefined behavior.  Suggest `return (*ia  > *ib) - (*ia  < *ib);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in lines:

- 68: initializer: const char *strings[]
- 55: argument: const char **array

or compile with `-Wno-write-strings`